# Is the jackknife estimate parametric or non-parametric?

Tags: nonparametric, jackknife

The jackknife is often described as non-parametric, and not relying on distributional assumptions.

For example: https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/06/21/jackknife-estimate-standard-error-sas.html says: "The jackknife method estimates the standard error (and bias) of statistics without making any parametric assumptions about the population that generated the data. It uses only the sample data."

However when I calculate the jackknife standard error of the mean it is identical to the plug-in formula:

Python example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from scipy.stats import bootstrap

np.random.seed(1234)
n = 5
y = np.random.uniform(0, 1, n)
df = pd.DataFrame({'y': y})
m = []
for i in range(n):
  new_df = df.drop(index=df.index[i], inplace = False)
  m.append(np.mean(new_df["y"]))

jack_se = (n - 1) * np.std(m, ddof = 1) / n**0.5
print(jack_se)

calc_se = df["y"].std() / (n**0.5)
print(calc_se)
```

Which gives:

```
0.11262904921394813
0.11262904921394809
```

The bootstrap standard error (which, to my understanding, is non-parametric) is consistently smaller, which is what I would expect:

```
print(bootstrap((df["y"],), np.mean).standard_error)
0.10078617321044048
```

Comment: If you work through the math, you will see that the jackknife estimate of the variance of the sample mean is indeed equal to the sample standard deviation divided by the sample size, i.e., the "usual" estimate.  The jackknife is still nonparametric, just as the sample mean itself is.

Comment: Thanks! But the jackknife is often suggested to be used when assumptions are violated, e.g. "When your data do not satisfy the assumptions ... you can use resampling techniques to estimate the standard error. " But if it's the same ... ?

Comment: The jackknife has far broader applicability than just estimating the standard error of the sample mean!  And... as the sample mean itself relies on no assumptions, except of course that there be a finite population mean, "when assumptions are violated" hardly applies in this case.

Comment: For example, you can use jackknife estimation when estimating parameters and SEs in regression models (to follow on @jbowman's comment).

Comment: Thanks. I use them when we have weighted samples. But I frequently am told that we also use them because we don't want to make distributional assumptions. Which seems wrong - but many sources seem to suggest that this is thew case.

Comment: It *is* the case, although of course, it isn't mandatory - there are other non-parametric techniques and you can rely on asymptotics sometimes too.  Why does it seem wrong?

Comment: Agree with that. It seems to say that if you're using a t-test (say) but you're worried about violating distributional assumptions, use a jackknife.  (You might rely on asymptotics, you might use a bootstrap or an exact test).